# Is asking for help how to complete a degree off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm 80 % done with a B.Sc. in computer science and I want to know how I should finish it, in what order, or if you think that I shouldn't complete the degree at all because I'm already employed full-time as an application developer and I also have another academic degree in another field (I have an M.Sc. in economics but I like and I work with computer programming and I'm not very interested in management.)

Would this question be off-topic because the answer possibly would help only me, because the answer would be subjective, or an inappropriate question for any other reason?

Answer (score 3):

The point of this board is to ask questions related to academic and research-oriented careers beyond the undergraduate level, as well as issues earlier on in the career that lead into them.

If you're planning to finish your bachelor's and then go into industry, this really isn't the place to ask that question. If you're planning, however, to continue on to master's studies, and want to know how to orient things so as to put yourself in the best possible light, that's a different subject altogether.